# Dual boot MacBook Pro 14.1 w/ Mojave/Ubuntu 22.04 won't set permanently macOS as default boot option after each Ubuntu session

Tags: startup, unix, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a partition. I'd like macOS 10.14.6 to be the default system to boot and having the possibility to choose Ubuntu only if I hold <kbd>option</kbd> key to get into the Mac startup manager, but Ubuntu takes over as the default system every time after I log into it. 
 My first try was changing the boot order with `sudo efibootmgr -o xxxx,xxxx`, and the second one was entering the Mac startup manager by holding <kbd>option</kbd>, then select the macOS option by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while clicking on the <kbd>↑</kbd> icon under macOS boot device. 
 Both work on the immediate (I automatically log into macOS if I reboot from both systems) but the first time I boot Ubuntu one of the described actions need to be remade (boot order is reset and Ubuntu is first again), otherwise  if I reboot the computer, I need to get into the startup manager to not get automatically into Ubuntu. 
 How could I **permanently** set macOS as the default boot option independently from the last used OS?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer places `.efi` files in the following folders on the hidden EFI partition. The MokManager is repeated with with the same filename and Secure Boot is repeated with different filenames.

| Type | Filenames in `EFI/Ubuntu` Folder | Filenames in `EFI/BOOT` Folder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Grub | `grubx64.efi` |  |
| MokManager | `mmx64.efi` | `mmx64.efi` |
| Secure Boot | `shimx64.efi` | `BOOTX64.EFI` |
| Fall Back |  | `fbx64.efi` |

The Mac Startup Manager only recognizes, as a boot option, the `BOOTX64.EFI` file in the `EFI/BOOT` folder. When selecting this option, the Secure Boot file will automatically make Ubuntu the default to boot.

---

### Possible Solution #1

Copy the `EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi` file to `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI` file. This will cause the Mac Startup Manger to instruct the firmware to boot Grub instead of Secure Boot. Grub will not change the boot order.

> Note: A future update to Ubuntu may undo this change.

---

### Possbile Solution #2

Install and configure the [rEFInd Boot Manager](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). (Preferable to the `EFI/BOOT` folder in a new EFI partition.)

Below are two possible ways to configure rEFInd.

- Always display a menu where the Grub installed with Ubuntu (or possibly just Ubuntu) could be chosen, but would by default always boot macOS after a short delay. In this case, you would make rEFInd the default to boot.
- Do not display a menu and always boot the Grub installed with Ubuntu (or possibly just Ubuntu). In this case, you would make macOS the default to boot.